# How can I determine if a dialog is null in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to show a simple dialog like this:

```
if (!aboutDialog)
        aboutDialog = new AboutDialog(this);
    aboutDialog->exec();
```

For some reason it doesn't work (aboutDialog has some pointer although is not initialized), the checking `if (aboutDialog == 0)` doesn't work either. I don't want to create the instance every time, but only once. How do I check this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize aboutDialog to 0 explicitly somewhere. Probably in the constructor of the class this member belongs to.

`(!aboutDialog)` is a correct test.

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Thing {
  void *data;
  public:
    Thing(){}
    void print() {
      std::cout << data << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Thing t;
  t.print();
  return 0;
 }
```

Try to compile that and run it multiple times. Chances are it will print something different each time. Why? Because `data` is uninitialized. It contains garbage. It has as much chance of being a null pointer than 0x1234ABCD or 42.

To fix it, `data` **needs** to be initialized somewhere. The simplest way here is just to do that in `Thing`'s constructor like below:

```
Thing() : data(0) {}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Although I didn't initialize the object but just only declared it nevertheless doesn't equal to zero or null.

Comment: That's the whole point. You **must** initialize it. Otherwise it will contain garbage data which is unlikely to be equal to a null pointer. There are circumstances where the language will default-initialize variables, but evidently you're not in one of them. So you must explicitly initialize it. BTW, turn on warnings on your compiler, it can often tell you when you're doing something like that.

Comment: I initialize it but only after checking if it's null or not. It's like a singleton. Firstly I check if it's null and initialize it if it's not and do nothing if it's already initialized. Look at my code. I'm trying to initialize it after checking. The problem is the checking doesn't work.

Comment: I've added to my answer. You **must** initialize all variables that are not guaranteed by the language to be default-initialized.

Comment: @seacat You do not quite understand the problem. In C++, just like in plain C, a variable is not initialized by declaring it. This is done for performance reasons. So if you have "int a; printf("%d", a);", it might give you 5, -1, or whatever. It might or might not be zero.

Comment: @Mat: you mean I should declare the dialog like this: myDialog = 0; ?

Comment: @sation I know that variable is not initialized by declaring. That's why I need this checking - first time when the dialog is not initialized I initialize it, but next time I just show (or exec) it. But I cannot check because the pointer for some reason has some value (it's not null, maybe some random I don't know), so how could I check if this variable was initialized or not yet?

Comment: @Mat by the way aboutDialog is pointer because I declare it: AboutDialog * about dialog;

Comment: If the dialog is a member variable of some class, then you need to set it to 0 in the class's constructor. You can do that either with the initialization list like I put in the example above, or simply with `aboutDialog = 0` in the body of the constructor.  When a variable is not initialized, **it contains garbage data**. Checking an uninitialized value is meaningless, the result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably not the best :) I use Qt with python, where you (in python) can write new attributes to a class whenever you want to "from the outside". If possible, I'd set a variable (again, maybe not the best practice) to some value when you construct aboutDialog. Then you can check if this is set later on. Like a state variable or something :)

Comment: Hmmm yeah it may works but firstly I would like to find some standard way. I just don't understand why the object is not null although it was not initialized but only declared.

Comment: Why in the world is this *better* than testing the `aboutDialog` variable itself? I don't know anything about Python, so I don't know if you have to do it this way there, but that sounds like a giant kludge. Also impossible to maintain. I don't suggest *anyone* doing this in C++.

Comment: @Seacat That's just the way C++ works: If you don't initialize a variable, it will have a random value (and most likely not 0). As a matter of fact, one _should_ initialize **all** member variables in the constructor. Everything else will cause you trouble, if not now, then some months later when you work on that class again. So just add 'aboutDialog = 0;' to the constructor as Mat suggested, and you're good!